Fix domain name in atlassian oauth flow that user is requested permission for
In Oauth when an app requests the auth code, there is a step which asks the user the website they want to give the permissions for
How we come to this flow is using https://auth.atlassian.com/authorize as specified in https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/oauth-2-3lo-apps/
Is it possible to show user only 1 website which we want to authenticate the app for and not allow them to choose multiple?
Which parameter to pass to the auth api for this?
I could not find any information documented about such a parameter
